# catch dismiss event in modal controller from main component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In my `MainPage`, I call the function create in `ModalController`, the `ModalPage` is shown and when I click on cancel, it calls dismiss function and return to `MainPage`. Everything works fine.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-page',
  templateUrl: 'main-page.html'
})
export class MainPage{
   itemTapped($event, item) {
       let detModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, {item : item});
       detModal.present();
   }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'modal-page',
  templateUrl: 'modal-page.html'
})
export class ModalPage{
   dismiss() {
     this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Now, I want to call a function in `MainPage` after the `ModalPage` has been dismissed. Is there any method ?

Comment: Can to create a plunkr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `onDidDismiss` ([docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/#advanced)) like this:

```
export class MainPage{
   itemTapped($event, item) {
       let detModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, {item : item});

       detModal.onDidDismiss(() => {
         // This will be executed after the modal is dismissed...
         console.log('Hi...');
       });

       detModal.present();
   }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)